# How to sort double array with another string array?

Tags: java, android

I try to sort a double array but with another string array:
It means
I have this:

```
Double[] values = {6.3, 5.5 , 7.0};
String [] names ={"samah","Dalal", "Mohammad"};
```

`samah` has `5.5` , `Dalal` has `6.3` and `Mohammad` has `7.0`

If I want to sort double values, it is simple using this:

```
Arrays.sort(values);
```

In this case the result is `{5.5,6.3,7.0}`

But how I will keep the names array with this sort??
result must be: `{"Dalal","samah","Mohammad"}`

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a new type that contains both values and implement `Comparable`.

```java
public class Person implements Comparable<Person> {

  private String name;
  private double score;

  public Person(final String name, final double score) {
    this.name = name;
    this.score = score;
  }

  public String getName() {
      return name;
  }

  public void setName(final String name) {
      this.name = name;
  }

  public double getScore() {
      return score;
  }

  public void setScore(final double score) {
      this.score = score;
  }

  @Override
  public int compareTo(final Person another) {
      return Double.compare(score, another.score);
  }
}
```

Now an array of `Person` should order by score when sorted with `Arrays.sort()`.

Comment: It might at some point make sense to sort people by name. So instead of having ```Person``` implement ```Comparable<...>``` and it having a fixed implementation. I would prefer to pass a ```Comparator``` when sorting: ```Arrays.sort(people, (x, y) -> Double.compare(x.getScore(), y.getScore()));```

Comment: That makes more sense than my answer, in fact.

Comment: Jorn What do you mean by "people" ?

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I am wrong, the objective is to store names and their corresponding values correctly, if that is the case then,

Why are you using two different arrays ?
Why don't you read values and names in a map?

If you read them in a map you won't have to face issues of maintaining the order of names and values.
If you do this the need for sorting will be reduced.

Comment: What do you mean by "map" ??

Comment: Maps as in hashmap or treemap, these are data structures in java.

Comment: Ok, I used `TreeMap tm = new TreeMap();` and in for loop i put `tm.put(country, new Double(d));`  so now i have many of countries and values,,, how i will sort using these values and get their countries?

Answer (score 0):

Use [TreeMap](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_treemap_class.htm) with keys as the double data and values as the String data. TreeMap is sorted automatically by its keys.

Comment: I try this now , I will let you know what will happen

Answer (score 0):

You can also solve this using `Comparator`. If you want sort based on marks, use `PersonMarksComparator`, If you want to sort it based on name use `PersonNameComparator`. It will be very useful if you want to sort it on multiple ways.

```
class PersonMarksComparator implements Comparator<Person> {

  @Override
  public int compare(Person person1, Person person2) {
      return Double.compare(person1.getMarks(), person2.getMarks());
  }
}

class PersonNameComparator implements Comparator<Person> {

  @Override
  public int compare(Person person1, Person person2) {
      return person1.getName().compareTo(person2.getName());
  }
}

public class Person {

   private String name;
   private double marks;

   public Person(final String name, final double marks) {
      this.name = name;
      this.marks = marks;
   }

   //getters and setters

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<Person>();
      Person person1 = new Person("samah", 5.5);
      Person person2 = new Person("Dalal", 6.3);
      Person person3 = new Person("Mohammad", 7.0);
      persons.add(person1);
      persons.add(person2);
      persons.add(person3);
      Collections.sort(persons, new PersonMarksComparator());
      Collections.sort(persons, new PersonNameComparator());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. (for Java8)

```
Double[] values = {6.3, 5.5 , 7.0};
String [] names ={"samah","Dalal", "Mohammad"};
String[] sortedNames = IntStream.range(0, names.length)
    .mapToObj(i -> i)
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(i -> values[i]))
    .map(i -> names[i])
    .toArray(String[]::new);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sortedNames));
```

result:

```
[Dalal, samah, Mohammad]
```

Process:

1. Make `IntStream` of indexes -> [0, 1, 2]
2. Convert each index to `Integer` object -> [0, 1, 2]
   (because IntStrem has no `sorted(Comparator)` method)
3. Sort each index by values[index] -> [1, 0, 2]
4. Map each index to names[index] -> ["Dalal", "samah", "Mohamand"]
5. Save the result as an array -> ["Dalal", "samah", "Mohamand"]

Comment: Sorry, it requires Java8.